# vuejs 3 + vuex + firebase. vuex action is not reactive

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I have a small app which implement login with firebase. After authorize, i need to fetch some data from firebase firestore, but calling vuex action don't make prop reactive update.

App.vue

```
<template>
    <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default {
    setup() {
        const store = useStore()
        
        onBeforeMount(() => {
            store.dispatch('fetchUser')
        })
    }
}
```

if fetchUser action in store i want to call getRole() action and set it in setUserRole mutation
store.js

store.js

```
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        user: null,
        role: null
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload
        },
        CLEAR_USER(state) {
            state.user = null
        },
        setUserRole(state, payload) {
            console.log('setUserRole dispatched', payload)
            state.role = payload
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchUser({ commit, dispatch }) {
            auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                if (user === null) {
                    commit('CLEAR_USER')
                } else {
                    dispatch('getRole', user.email)
                    commit('setUser', user)
                    if (router.isReady() && router.currentRoute.value.path === '/auth') {
                        router.push('/')
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        async getRole({commit}, userEmail) {
            console.log('action getRole', userEmail)
            const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("email", "==", userEmail));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
            querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
                commit('setUserRole', doc.data())
            });
        },
        async login({commit, dispatch}, { email, password }){
            const response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            if (response) {
                dispatch('getRole', response.user.email)
                
                commit('setUser', response.user)
            } else {
                throw new Error('login failed')
            }
        },

        async logout(context){
            await signOut(auth)
            context.commit('setUser', null)
        }
    }
})

// export the store
export default store
```

after router.push('/') i`m redirectiong to "/" page but cant access to state.role

homePage.vue

```
<template>
    <headerLine />
    home page
</template>
<script>
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

    import headerLine from '../components/headerLine'
    
    export default {
        components: { headerLine },
        setup() {
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

and finally headerLine.vue

```
<template>
<div>{{role}}</div>
</template>
<script>
    import store from '../store'
    
    export default {
        setup() {
            return {
                role: store.state.role
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I have tried to get it in beforeMount hook, and call action in it there are was no result.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i tried with it for two hours, and find solution after 5 min after posting this question. Hope it will useful:
In vue component need to use [computed props](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) like (in vue3):

```html
<script>
    import store from '../store'
    import { computed } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
        setup() {
            const role = computed(() => store.state.role)
            return {
                role
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```